# How to show a ListBox item outside the ListBox control and over all other controls on Item click

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In my solution, I have a `ListBox` control that is being populated dynamically with items and my `ListBox` has a defined height and width. I have a content template that is defined in `ItemContainerStyle`. When I click on each item I get a menu under them and that works. But the only problem I am facing is how to show that menu in the last row of List Box control(actually for the last items which are being placed in the bottom) without the menu being cut off? So, if select the first item in the `ListBox` my menu expands and if I select the last item my menu is cut off. I wanted to use `ZIndex` and I managed to access it but the item won't show outside the defined size and being of the `ListBox` control. I can provide code but there is a WPF `ListBox` control with defined as said ItemContainerStyle where I have toggle button control and finally in a style of that toggle button control I set a `ContentTemplate` which has a stack panel and my menu items in it(text block and buttons). You can find attached an image that shows exactly what I want to confirm, `ZIndex` is not working and I don't want to scroll. I want to say that I tried with `Preview Mouse Up Event handler` and I can find it as I said but setting `ZIndex` is not working. Also, I tried with `triggers` of the border which is a panel around my menu but nothing. I am looking forward to hearing from you.

[image]

CODEUPDATE:

LISTBOX CONTROL

```
<ListBox x:Name="siteslist" MinWidth="505" MaxWidth="650" MaxHeight="205"
SelectedItem="{Binding DataContext.CurrentViewModel.SelectedMyValue, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.CurrentViewModel.MyValueView, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
Style="{DynamicResource SiteListBoxStyle}"
ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource SiteListBoxItemStyle}"
ItemsPanel="{DynamicResource SiteItemsPanelTemplate}" PreviewMouseDown="Siteslist_OnPreviewMouseDown"
/>
```

EVENT FOR ZINDEX - NOT WORKING

```
private void Siteslist_OnPreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
     var item = ItemsControl.ContainerFromElement(sender as ListBox, e.OriginalSource as DependencyObject) as ListBoxItem;
     if (item != null)
     {
        item.SetValue(Canvas.ZIndexProperty, 5);
     }
}
```

STYLE FOR LIST BOX ITEM

```
<Style x:Key="SiteListBoxItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,0,0,0"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,34,0,0"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource TransparentBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource BorderTextBoxBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,0,0"/>
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource FocusVisual}"/>
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource ListBoxItemDataTemplate}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
          <Setter.Value>
              <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                 <Border x:Name="siteactions" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true"
                      Height="{Binding Height, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}">
                    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                  </Border>
               <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <MultiTrigger>
                 <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
           <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
           <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="True"/>
                     </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
          <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" TargetName="siteactions" Value="100"/>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                 <MultiTrigger>
                 <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                      <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
                      </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                      <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="siteactions" Value="Blue"/>
                         <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="siteactions" Value="2"/>
                            </MultiTrigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

CONTENT TEMPLATE OF LIST BOX ITEM

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ListBoxItemDataTemplate" DataType="{x:Type models:Site}">
                <ToggleButton x:Name="choosesite" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}" 
                             Content="{Binding MyValue}" Tag="{Binding Location}" 
                             Style="{DynamicResource SiteButtonStyle}"
                             Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.CurrentViewModel.ClickSiteCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
                             CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=choosesite, Path=IsChecked}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
```

TOGGLE BUTTON STYLE

```
<Style x:Key="SiteButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource FocusVisual}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Button.Static.Border}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource Button.Static.Border}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource Button.Static.Background}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="Auto"/>
        <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource SiteButtonTemplate}"/>
        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource SiteDataTemplate}"/>
    </Style>
```

CONTENT DATA TEMPLATE - MY MENU

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="SiteDataTemplate">
        <StackPanel x:Name="SiteActionsPanel" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" > <!--Height="40"-->
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Center" FontWeight="SemiBold"  
                       Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="sitelocation" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Roboto" FontSize="11" 
                       Foreground="{DynamicResource GrayButtonBrush}"
                       Text="{Binding Path=Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ToggleButton}}}"/>
            <Border x:Name="SiteActionsBorder" >
                <StackPanel Margin="0,20,0,0" x:Name="SiteActions" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Visibility="Collapsed">
                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Button x:Name="choose" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" Style="{DynamicResource ChooseButtonStyle}" Content="Choose" Grid.Row="0" Panel.ZIndex="99"
                            Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.CurrentViewModel.ChooseSiteCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}"/>
                        <ToggleButton x:Name="delete" Width="70" Grid.Row="1" Panel.ZIndex="99"
                              IsChecked="{Binding DataContext.CurrentViewModel.IsDeleteConfirmed, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
                              Style="{StaticResource DeleteConfirmToggleButtonStyle}"
                              Command="{Binding DataContext.CurrentViewModel.ConfirmDeleteSiteCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
                              CommandParameter=""/>
                        <Button x:Name="edit" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" Style="{DynamicResource EditButtonStyle}" Content="Edit" Panel.ZIndex="99" Grid.Row="2"
                                    Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.CurrentViewModel.EditSiteCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </StackPanel>
       <DataTemplate.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsPressed, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" TargetName="sitelocation" Value="{DynamicResource ChoosenButtonBrush}"/>
                <!--<Setter Property="Height" TargetName="SiteActionsPanel" Value="155"/>-->
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="SiteActions" Value="Visible"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" TargetName="sitelocation" Value="{DynamicResource ChoosenButtonBrush}"/>
                <!--<Setter Property="Height" TargetName="SiteActionsPanel" Value="155"/>-->
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=DataContext.CurrentViewModel.IsChoosenSite, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="SiteActions" Value="Collapsed"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Please supply minimal code and markup to reproduce your issue. If you do not, it is likely that your question will be closed.

Comment: I did it. @Andy Any comments about what should do? So, to confirm, the menu is being shown but cut in the bottom and I just want that menu over the controls and outside the ListBox control.

Comment: If you want a control to be displayed outside the panel, you need to put if into a [Popup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/popup-overview)

Comment: Example sir @KlausGütter? The thing is that i have working  and not sure if I could change that to be a popup like in datepickers controls and everything is as I want to be but the problem is the bottom row.

Comment: A child control simply cannot paint outside the borders of its parent control (your list box). Therefore it must be in a popup or similar (e.g. ContextMenu)

Comment: Did you think about using a contextmenu?

Comment: I am not the one who can think about the context menu :) and my task is to show that menu completely and that is it. so, i tried with zindex which people claim that it should work and besides that i can set the height of my custom menu but it will make the same space between all other rows in list box and finally it will scroll automatically and that is it. @Andy

Comment: A WinForms Combobox does what you want: https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0GW7.png Maybe you can switch to a WPF Combobox?

Comment: as i can see combobox control does that in a form but not as a list box item and for now i don't have the option allowed - to change structure or similar. i can only do something with the current solution and i wanted to get any kind of information from someone who perhaps saw something like this. thank you sir @ThomasWeller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make a custom drop-down menu over items but the final solution was to change the size of items and on selection, pressing the item the height property is changed and my menu is being showed - it works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `ContextMenu` to host your menu. Because `ContextMenu` opens on right click by default you would have to manually open it on left click (or `ListBoxItem.Selected` or whatever custom trigger you want).
The advantage of a `ContextMenu` over a `Popup` is that the `ContextMenu` already implements the usual focus behavior. In addition the menu items are looking like common context menu items without further configuration and layout modifications.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
  <EventSetter Event="MouseLeftButtonUp"
               Handler="ListBoxItem_MouseLeftButtonUp" />
  <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ContextMenu>
        <MenuItem Header="Menu Item #1" Click="Click event handler" />
        <MenuItem Header="Menu Item #2" Command="Alternative command handler" />
        <MenuItem Header="Menu Item #3" />
      </ContextMenu>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
private void ListBoxItem_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
  var listBoxItem = sender as ListBoxItem;
  listBoxItem.ContextMenu.IsOpen = true;
}
```