# WPF ListBox item scroll/setting a new position when clicking and showing a drop down menu does not work

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox, listboxitem

I have a ListBox control where I have some custom items with custom drop-down menus(my question from a couple of days ago - [How to show a ListBox item outside the ListBox control and over all other controls on Item click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76367378/how-to-show-a-listbox-item-outside-the-listbox-control-and-over-all-other-contro)).

Now, I have a new problem and I am attaching a video clip. so, I would like my bottom items to behave as the one above on clicking the item. So, when I click on the bottom item I want the upper item to go up in order to show the drop-down menu of the last on item. You can see that when I click the above items they change the size and move the bottom item in order to show the drop-down menu. The same principle is working on other custom listbox but here not and perhas because of thise custom items(which are only present here). Please take a look at the video clip I am sending. You can find the data template code which defines the item.[image]

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MYListBoxItemDataTemplate" DataType="{x:Type models:MyType}">
        <StackPanel x:Name="itemsactions" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="135">
            <ToggleButton x:Name="choose" Height="52" Margin="0,27,0,0"
                          IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}"
                          Command="{Binding DataContext.CurrentViewModel.ClickPalletTypeCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
                          CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
                          Style="{DynamicResource CircledTransparentToggleButtonStyle}">
                <Image x:Name="image" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,0" Height="52" Stretch="Uniform">
                    <Image.Source>
                        <BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding ImageSource.Regular}"/>
                    </Image.Source>
                </Image>
            </ToggleButton>
            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                <Label Margin="0,15,0,0" Width="152" HorizontalAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" 
                       FontSize="14" FontWeight="SemiBold" 
                       Content="{Binding Weight}" 
                       Style="{DynamicResource LeftLoginTextBoxBlockLabelStyle}"/>
                <Label Margin="0,2,0,0" Width="152" HorizontalAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" 
                       FontSize="14" 
                       Content="{Binding Size}" 
                       Style="{DynamicResource LeftLoginTextBoxBlockLabelStyle}"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Margin="0,34,0,0" x:Name="subactions" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Visibility="Collapsed">
                <ToggleButton x:Name="delete" IsTabStop="False" Width="70"
                              IsChecked="{Binding DataContext.CurrentViewModel.IsDeleteConfirmed, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
                              Style="{StaticResource DeleteConfirmToggleButtonStyle}"
                              Command="{Binding DataContext.CurrentViewModel.ConfirmDeletePalletTypeCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
                              CommandParameter=""/>
                <Button x:Name="edit" IsTabStop="False" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" Style="{DynamicResource EditButtonStyle}" Content="Edit"
                        Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.CurrentViewModel.EditPalletTypeCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsChecked, ElementName=choose}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="subactions" Value="Visible"/>
                <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="itemsactions" Value="200"/>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, ElementName=choose}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Source" TargetName="image" Value="{Binding ImageSource.MouseOver}"/>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsPressed, ElementName=choose}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Source" TargetName="image" Value="{Binding ImageSource.Pressed}"/>
                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="subactions" Value="Visible"/>
                <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="itemsactions" Value="200"/>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=choose}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Source" TargetName="image" Value="{Binding ImageSource.Choosen}"/>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsEnabled, ElementName=choose}" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Source" TargetName="image" Value="{Binding ImageSource.Disabled}"/>
                <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="itemsactions" Value="135"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
    </DataTemplate>
```

UPDATE - WORKING CONTROL LISTBOX:[image]

Comment: Why don't you like to show the expanded context in a context menu or popup as suggested in your linked question??

Comment: If you don't use a context menu or popup you would have to scroll up the listbox manually in order to give the item enough space to display fully. This would result in a bad UX as the list would constantly scroll itself and push items out of view. Using a contextmenu or popup will improve the behavior/experience.

Comment: because i didn't make it and i don't make any decisions about it. anyway, i am looking forward to an answer of anyone who had let's say similar experiences and that is it. the same code is working in other listbox and here not. @BionicCode

Comment: I don't know the difference between this on-working code and the one that works. But from what you have shown so far I can tell that the issue is related to the way you expand the items. You are simpoly changing the size of the expanded item causing it consume more vertical space. If the item is growing/expanding it pushes down the rows below. If this happens to a top row i.e. the first visible row the space created below is enough to show the complete item. but when it happens to an item in a row that is close to the bounds of the ListBox the content gets clipped.

Comment: To make the complete item visible you would have to scroll it up e.g. to the top of the viewport in order to create enough space for it to display. If you don't want to overlay your expanded content you must scroll the expanded item row to the top. How to do that depends on the Panel you are using. If this is a custom Panel you must implement ISscrollInfo properly so that for example you can correctly scroll by item index (like StackPanel would do).

Comment: By the way, no reason to get rude. I was just asking to understand your motivation. It seems you chose the worse of the two options that's why I was asking. Never meant to criticize you.

Comment: i am sorry if i "sounded" rude but i am not, i just don't have time to explain and that is it. just want a "experience answer" from some expert who perhaps had the same problem and that is it(in short as everyone else here). and i am going to upload another example and the thing is that i can not describe the issue because everything it is defined the same as in others and that is it. just a moment @BionicCode.

Comment: If this is a custom Panel you must implement ISscrollInfo properly so that for example you can correctly scroll by item index (like StackPanel would do). i don't have a custom panel, nothing except common things everyone can see and again the problem is that same solution does not work on two same controls with different items. as everyone can see, there are triggers in the datatemplate which define the height and those triggers bring the magic but listbox control is acting odd and that is it. thanks @BionicCode.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254033/discussion-between-ferid-s-sejdovic-and-bioniccode).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The working control has three elements in the expanded panel opposed to the two elements in the non-working container. This gives the `ListBoxItem` a greater height. It seems that this is enough to trigger the `ListBox` to scroll the item into view.

You can try two things:

1. add a third element to the expanded container (or generally increase the expanded item height)
2. Handle the `ListBox.SelectionChanged` or `ToggleButton.Clicked` event, get the selected item container in the handler and call `FrameworkElement.BringIntoView()`. This could be enough to scroll the complete item into view automatically.

```xml
<ListBox SelectionChanged="OnSelectionChanged" />
```

```cs
private void OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
  var listBox = sender as ListBox;
  var selectedItemContainer = listBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(listBox.SelectedItem) as FrameworkElement;
  selectedItemContainer?.BringIntoView();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The dropdown exists "inside" the parent of the toggle button thing. The grid layout you are using probably gets resized to fit, and then voila! Everything is redrawn 'correctly' to fit the new content that is 'inside the parent'.

I don't write much xaml (I just use the events and write c# code...), but I suppose you somehow need to stop the resize of your grid, or mark the stack panel you make visible NOT a child of the button's parent.

I don't know how to do either.